# Compiling Veins4.5 on Omnet++ 5.1 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, omnet++, veins

am trying to build veins on OMNet++5.1on ubuntu 14.04  but cant get it to work.  both veins 4.4 and veins 4.5 give the same error. here is my stack trace:

```
18:40:54 **** Build of configuration gcc-debug for project veins ****
make MODE=debug all
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/veins-veins-4.4/src'
MSGC: veins/base/messages/AirFrame.msg
MSGC: veins/base/messages/BorderMsg.msg
MSGC: veins/base/messages/ChannelSenseRequest.msg
MSGC: veins/base/messages/MacPkt.msg
MSGC: veins/modules/messages/AirFrame11p.msg
MSGC: veins/modules/messages/Mac80211Pkt.msg
MSGC: veins/modules/messages/PhyControlMessage.msg
MSGC: veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg
veins/base/connectionManager/BaseConnectionManager.cc
veins/base/connectionManager/ChannelAccess.cc
veins/base/connectionManager/ConnectionManager.cc
veins/base/connectionManager/NicEntryDebug.cc
veins/base/connectionManager/NicEntryDirect.cc
veins/base/modules/BaseApplLayer.cc
veins/base/modules/BaseBattery.cc
veins/base/modules/BaseLayer.cc
veins/base/modules/BaseMacLayer.cc
veins/base/modules/BaseMobility.cc
veins/base/modules/BaseModule.cc
veins/base/modules/BaseWorldUtility.cc
veins/base/modules/BatteryAccess.cc
veins/base/phyLayer/BaseDecider.cc
veins/base/phyLayer/BasePhyLayer.cc
veins/base/phyLayer/ChannelInfo.cc
veins/base/phyLayer/ChannelState.cc
veins/base/phyLayer/Decider.cc
veins/base/phyLayer/MappingBase.cc
veins/base/phyLayer/MappingUtils.cc
veins/base/phyLayer/PhyUtils.cc
veins/base/phyLayer/Signal.cc
veins/base/utils/asserts.cc
veins/base/utils/Coord.cc
veins/base/utils/NetwToMacControlInfo.cc
veins/base/utils/SimpleAddress.cc
veins/base/utils/winsupport.cc
veins/modules/analogueModel/BreakpointPathlossModel.cc
veins/modules/analogueModel/JakesFading.cc
veins/modules/analogueModel/LogNormalShadowing.cc
veins/modules/analogueModel/NakagamiFading.cc
veins/modules/analogueModel/PERModel.cc
veins/modules/analogueModel/SimpleObstacleShadowing.cc
veins/modules/analogueModel/SimplePathlossModel.cc
veins/modules/analogueModel/TwoRayInterferenceModel.cc
veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc
veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc
veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemoRSU11p.cc
veins/modules/application/traci/TraCITestApp.cc
veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.cc
veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIBuffer.cc
veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIColor.cc
veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.cc
veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc
veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.cc
veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc
veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerInet.cc
veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.cc
veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.cc: In member function ‘virtual void Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd::init_traci()’:
veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.cc:91:39: error: ‘class omnetpp::cXMLElement’ has no member named ‘tostr’
  std::string contents = launchConfig->tostr(0);
                                       ^
make[1]: *** [../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/veins-veins-4.4/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

18:41:46 Build Finished (took 52s.0ms)
Please help me out

Comment: if you check the official website (http://veins.car2x.org/download), you will see that the latest version(s) of Veins do not support OMNeT++ 5.1 yet. **Veins is now compatible with OMNeT++ 5 (as of the OMNeT++ 5.0 release candidate)**

Comment: Thanks let me compile using Omnet++ 5.0